# Woocommerce Subscriptions getting added as line items in cart after payment made

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

Subscription data that seems as though it was previously captured is being added sporadically to customer orders once payment has been made and they are on the thank you page. The customer will receive all the subscription line items in their thankyou page and they will also appear on the order edit page.

I am currently working on a staging environment so subscriptions that have being brought over from the live site are under manual renewal.

I cannot see any valid reason for this? Any help? All plugins are up to date and appears to be no conflict when turning on and off plugins

Woocommerce V3.2.6

Woocommerce Subscriptions V 2.2.11

Comment: I think that the only possible reason should be around the payment gateway, as automated subscriptions needs specific enabled payment gateways. You can check that in WC settings > status. Go at the end of the page in "Subscriptions" section… See also compatible payment gateways in subscriptions official docs…

Comment: In subscriptions it is red cross as it is in staging mode, paypal is set up for recurring payment. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I suppose yes… The staging mode is automatically set by Subscriptions when the payment gateway is not set correctly or when it's not a compatible payment gateway… For further support, you should better contact support threads of the subscriptions plugin and/or the payment gateway plugin.